# Tensorflow.js : TypeError : backend.select is not a function

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am making a color classifier using **tensorflow.js**. The methodology of training is to show a color in the canvas and there are 10 buttons which has 10 colors associated with and the user needs to click any one of the button to select the color. Taking the input from the buttons,normalizing the colors and applying `tf.oneHot`, the tensors look like this. rgb color and the label

```
Tensor
     [[0.772549, 0.3568628, 0.9098039],]
Tensor
     [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],]
```

Then we take the colors and train the model. Every time the user clicks the button, model gets trained and gets better. This is my model configuration

```
const model = tf.sequential();

const hidden = tf.layers.dense({
    units: 16,
    inputShape: [3],
    activation: "relu"
});
model.add(hidden);
const output = tf.layers.dense({
    units: 10,
    activation: "softmax"
});
model.add(output);

const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(0.25);
model.compile({
    optimizer: optimizer,
    loss: "categoricalCrossentropy",
    metrics: ["accuracy"]
});
```

Now i'm getting an error called `TypeError: backend.select is not a function` It would be nice if someone tells me what this error actually means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem in `tfjs-node` version `0.1.9` according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/560).

A quick `npm update` updated it to `0.1.10`, which seems to have solved the problem!

Comment: @KaelKirl Thanks for the info. That was a great help. Solved my problem :)